# log4j DEBUG log logging to catalina.out but not in file in unix

Tags: java, log4j

I implemented log4j logging in my JSF application.My log4j.properties file is like this

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, fileout

#----------------------------- All logging to console-----------------------------

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] [%t] %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# ------------------------------ All Logging to File------------------------------

log4j.appender.fileout = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileout.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileout.layout.ConversionPattern = [%d] [%t] %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.fileout.File = ${catalina.home}/logs/Portal-alllogs.log
log4j.appender.fileout.MaxFileSize =2MB
log4j.appender.fileout.MaxBackupIndex =2
```

Now i get the following exception in my application because the DB is down

```
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.<init>(OracleConnection.java:361)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.getConnectionInstance(OracleDriver.java:485)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
```

**The problem is the above exception shows up in catalina.out,but not in my log file**

Can anybody please explain why?
Thanks in advance

**Update**:I just see this log while deploying the WAR file

```
WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference

    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
    ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
    Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
    )
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
            at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
            at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getLogWriter(BasicDataSource.java:1098)
            at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:350)
            at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:156)
            at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:143)
            at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:304)
            at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:826)
            at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:145)
            at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:814)
            at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1021)
     at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1021)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:631)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:237)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5103)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:932)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:723)
     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:932)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:723)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:470)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:379)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:324)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the exception is actually LOGGED to stdout, not just PRINTED to stdout? Can you spot the conversion pattern working on what you get to your console?

Comment: I have updated my question.While uploading my WAR itself i get the above exception.

Comment: I'm still not seeing that it's using the "log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] [%t] %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n". If I were you I'd try to make sure the webapp deploys and starts properly first, and worry about logging later.

Comment: Is it because during the uploading of WAR i am getting the exception,i can't see it in log file?

Comment: That would be my guess, yes. How do you "upload the war"?

Comment: I got my mistake.I was actually doing `e.printStackTrace` instead of `LOGGER.debug("Exception",e)`. I have changed it.Now i see my log in the Log file.Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a permissions problem - check the owners and permissions of the ${catalina.home}/logs directory.

Comment: Thanks for the response.All the folder permissions are -rw-r---- in logs directory.All the remaining log shows up in both file and catalina.out.but my exception doesn't show up in my log file

Answer (score 0):

Do you catch that exception in your code and handle it, that is log it? If not, why do you expect to show up in your log?

Comment: @bpgergo-I am using tomcat connection pooling in my application and i declared it in my context.xml of my application.But now because my database is down,this exception is getting throwed.I am catching this exception,but in the log i don't see my java file from where it is getting throwed.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a permissions problem: verify that ${catalina.home} resolves to where you think it does -- try using a "raw" absolute path to rule that out.

Comment: @PapaFreud-Thanks for the response.${catalina.home} is resolving correctly because i am able to see my log files in ${catalina.home}/logs directory only